# Compiling Sphere_2.6a library on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos

I am trying to compiling sphere_2.6a library on Mac OS X. At the beginning the following parameters are required:

```
Defined Commands and Options:
  Compiler           = gcc
  Compiler options   = -g -m32 -DNARCH_UNIX
  Install            = cp
  Ranlib             = ranlib
  Archiver           = ar ru
```

The is that I get the following error output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_hs_getopt", referenced from:
   _main in cc36C6uK.o
"_hs_optind", referenced from:
   _main in cc36C6uK.o
"_sp_create_header", referenced from:
  _main in cc36C6uK.o
"_sp_fpcopy", referenced from:
  _main in cc36C6uK.o
"_sp_get_version", referenced from:
  _main in cc36C6uK.o
"_sp_verbose", referenced from:
  _main in cc36C6uK.o
"_sp_write_header", referenced from:
  _main in cc36C6uK.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [h_add] Error 1
```

Does anybody know where is the problem?

Thanks a lot,
Giovanni

Comment: You are missing some libraries to link against.

Comment: Do you know which ones?

Comment: Do a google search for those symbols and you might find the libraries you need.

Comment: Yes, I did it. But there is no suggestion...